# Remove colon and convert it to number in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a element in XML:
`<duration>00:08:90</duration>`.
I am using XSLT to create a XML with elements required for my system.

Firstly I want my XSLT to remove the colons to look like this: 000890
Then I want to do a if-test to check whether this number is less than (<) 001000

Comment: Which XSLT engine are you using?  .Net?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the translate function to remove the colons:

```
translate(., ':', '')
```

then for the number value checking you can do the following:

```
number(.) < 1000
```

so if the xml was like:

```
<xml>
    <tag>00:08:90</tag>
</xml>
```

Then you could have the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="test" select="number(translate(/xml/tag, ':', '')) &lt; 1000" />
<!-- $test will = true() -->
```

Check out this [zvon xslt number function reference](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/OutputOverview/function_number_frame.html) for the acceptable values for `number()` to do the correct error checking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:if test="number(translate(duration, ':', '')) &lt; 1000">
  <!-- do something -->
</xsl:if>
```

Unless there is no way for the duration value to be invalid/mis-formatted, pay extra attention to it's length and also to `'NaN'` values that could be returned by `number()`.